Batch processing mongo db documents to CSV file
I have a task given to convert a collection of mongo db documents to CSV files. The documents are customer purchases. There is almost a million purchases happening from many customers. I want to write it to a CSV file, where the size of the csv doesn't cross 100mb. The main problem Is that the customer items purchased together in an order should be in the same file. Also I need to parallely process it using threading. The problem is that the order is and users are in millions so I cannot write each of them to a single file. Any ideas how to solve this using spring batch. The documents contain the purchase_id and the order_id.
I tried everything, from grouping order IDs using aggregation in mongo db and creating 10 partitions using the task executor. But it was very slow and it caused some thread to have huge documents list meanwhile other had few.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The chunk oriented processing model of spring batch is not suitable for aggregation, but you can use the driving query pattern https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders. The reader would grab the order (by order id), and the processor would query for the current order's items. This pattern is known to be slow for large datasets (but it should be ok for small/medium datasets) as it issues an additional query for each item. This is an issue with the pattern itself, not spring batch.

How can we do it parallelly. Even though we read all the orders by userid there would be some thread still getting huge amounts of order details to process and some threads getting very less.

I can't seem to do anything about this. We need all the threads to get the same amount of orders to process or the other threads would have to wait.

You can't control which how much data each thread will have. What you can control is the range of orders to distribute to each worker (you can implement this in the partitioner). So in your case, you can give each worker the same number of orders to process, but you can't know upfront how much data each thread will have (some threads will have orders with 10 items, other will have orders  with 100 items, etc).
